# InvalidClientTokenID error when running Terraform Plan/Apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm setting up a HA cluster in AWS using Terraform and user data. My main.tf looks like this:

```
provider "aws" {
access_key = "access_key"
secret_key = "secret_key"
}

resource "aws_instance" "etcd" {
ami = "${var.ami}" // coreOS 17508
instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
key_name = "${var.key_name}"
key_path = "${var.key_path}"
count = "${var.count}"
region = "${var.aws_region}"
user_data = "${file("cloud-config.yml")}"

subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.k8s.id}"
private_ip = "${cidrhost("10.43.0.0/16", 10 + count.index)}"
associate_public_ip_address = true

vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.terraform_swarm.id}"]

tags {
name = "coreOS-master"
}
}
```

However, when I run `terraform plan` I get the following error `provider.aws: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
    status code: 403, request id: 45099d1a-4d6a-11e8-891c-df22e6789996`

I've looked around some suggestions were to clear out my ~/.aws/credentials file or update it with the new aws IAM credentials. I'm pretty lost on how to fix this error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is usually caused by some certain characters (\ @ !, etc) in the credentials. It can be fixed by re-generating credentials your aws access code and secret key.

Answer (score 14):

This is a general error that can be cause by a few reasons.

Some examples:

1)  Invalid credentials passed as environment variables or in `~/.aws/credentials`.

*Solution: Remove old profiles / credentials  and clean all your environment vars*:

```
for var in AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN ; do eval unset $var ; done
```

2) When your `aws_secret_access_key` contains characters like the plus-sign `+` or multiple forward-slash `/`. See more in [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2972). 
*Solution:  Delete credentials and generate new ones.*

3) When you try to execute Terraform inside a region which must be explicitly enabled (and wasn't). 
(In my case it was `me-south-1 (Bahrain)` - See more in [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2220-august-01-2019)).
*Solution: Enable region or move to an enabled one.*

4) In cases where you work with 3rd party tools like [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) and don't supply valid AWS credentials to communicate with - See more in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vault-tool/6mpSUpu61zo).

**All will lead to a failure of aws `sts:GetCallerIdentity` API.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your access key and secret are correct. I have used Static credentials and substituting variables using variables.tf. The latest error also points to the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html). Start with making Static Credentials work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it. I actually changed two things before I tried again, so not sure which one solved the issue.

I managed to create new creds without any "special" characters (+/ etc).

I then included a shared credentials file in my .tf file under "provider".

```
provider "aws" {
shared_credentials_file = "\\wsl$\\Debian\\home\\user\\.aws\\credentials"
region = var.region
}
```

When I ran `terraform plan -out myplan.tfplan` it completed!

Comment: Please try to be precise on your replies. Your response looks more like a guess than a solution to the problem. If you can't  identify what really solve the issue you're wild guessing and that's an absolute (no no) in programming and development.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I narrowed it down to the shared credentials file - even if there were special characters in my password it still completed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error and resolve it just by reinserting AWS credentials correctly. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem running Terraform in a Lambda function when I was setting the "access_key" and "secret_key" properties in the AWS provider, but I had not set "token".

This was solved by not setting any property but "region" in the AWS provider and letting the provider pull what it needed from the environment - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN.