# InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid. status code: 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am using, terraform & kubectl to deploy insfra-structure and application.

Since I changed aws configure :

`terraform init`

`terraform apply`

I always got :

```
terraform apply

Error: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
    status code: 403, request id: 5ba38c31-d39a-11e9-a642-21e0b5cf5c0e

  on providers.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
   1: provider "aws" {
```

Can you advise ? Appreciate !

Comment: You should share your terraform configuration, or at least a minimal example, otherwise it's tough to tell what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121871/invalidclienttokenid-error-when-running-terraform-plan-apply/59314272#59314272).

This is a general error that can be cause by a few reasons.

Some examples:

1)  Invalid credentials passed as environment variables or in `~/.aws/credentials`.

*Solution: Remove old profiles / credentials  and clean all your environment vars*:

```
for var in AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN ; do eval unset $var ; done
```

2) When your `aws_secret_access_key` contains characters like the plus-sign `+` or multiple forward-slash `/`. See more in [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2972). 
*Solution:  Delete credentials and generate new ones.*

3) When you try to execute Terraform inside a region which must be explicitly enabled (and wasn't). 
(In my case it was `me-south-1 (Bahrain)` - See more in [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2220-august-01-2019)).
*Solution: Enable region or move to an enabled one.*

4) In cases where you work with 3rd party tools like [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) and don't supply valid AWS credentials to communicate with - See more in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vault-tool/6mpSUpu61zo).

**All will lead to a failure of aws `sts:GetCallerIdentity` API.**

Comment: For my problem... Solution number 2 was the issue. Why produce + symbols if they are so troublesome?!

Comment: 2) Pretty much always having + or /

Comment: Adding to 1), my experience has been that having an `~/.aws/credentials` interferes with authenticating via `aws sso`. So removing the file resolved the error.

Comment: What happened in my case was I was creating the credentials dynamically using vault and trying to use it immediately.
I had to wait at least 5 seconds after the credentials are created before using them.

Comment: What do you mean by "enable region" in solution number 3?

Comment: Not all regions are enabled by default.

Comment: If all of the points above is not working, then try to create new credentials for your user in AWS console and set those credentials using aws configure. This worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it turned out that I had the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` set. This circumvented my `~/.aws/credentials` file. Simply unsetting these environment variables worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

I got the same invalid token error after adding an S3 Terraform backend.

It was because I was missing a `profile` attribute on the new backend.

This was my setup when I got the invalid token error:

```
# ~/.aws/credentials

[default]
aws_access_key_id=OJA6...
aws_secret_access_key=r2a7...

[my_profile_name]
aws_access_key_id=RX9T...
aws_secret_access_key=oaQy...
```

```json
// main.tf

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "terraform-state"
    encrypt        = true
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-locks"
  }
}
```

And this was the fix that worked (showing a diff, I added the line with "+" at the beginning):

```diff
  // main.tf

  terraform {
    backend "s3" {
      bucket         = "terraform-state"
      // ...
+     profile        = "my_profile_name"
    }
  }
```

None of the guides or videos I read or watched included the `profile` attribute. But it's explained in the Terraform documentation, here:

https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to VS Code Debug Console: The `AWS_PROFILE` and `AWS_REGION` environment variables were not loaded. For solving that I closed vscode and reopened  through CLI using the command `code <project-folder>`.

Answer (score 0):

I used **aws configure** and provide my Keys as shown below

See image of the error I got

[image: 1]

But I still got the invalid token error.

**Answer**

I have cleaned everything from **~/.aws/credentials** and then run **aws configure** again and provided my keys.

It worked for me. Try it too

Answer (score 0):

There can be two problems for this

1. AWS credentials (access key id and secret) might have to reconfigured
   so use aws configure to update the credentials.
2. In the aws portals if your creds are not used for long time they might be inactive. Please go ahead and activate them and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error even though my credentials were working and valid. It turned out to be because the cloudformation stack I was uploading was creating an IAM role, and AWS requires you use MFA in order to create IAM roles. So adding MFA and getting my security token with `--serial-number` and `--token-code` fixed the problem for me.